# How to time ListBox load time WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, load-time, data-virtualization

I'm playing around with DataVirtualization and Async. What are some options I have for quantifying load times of a ListBox that I'm binding my virtualized data collections to?

I need a way to compare the virtualized vs non-virtualized data loading. Have been unsuccessful in locating any resources for this topic.

Should I just put a stopwatch on the ListBox_Loaded event in the code behind?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fail to understand what does `ListBox` have to do with your DATA load times. BTW this question is unclear.

Comment: The only part I understood was he wishes to compare loading time between virtualized and non-virtualized ListBox. I suggest you to start your StopWatch on event ListBox.Initalized. And to stop your StopWatch on event ListBox.Loaded.

Comment: I meant the data loaded BY the `ListBox`, which is being loaded in "pages." Or in the cases where I am not virtualizing any data, I need to know how long it takes to load data into the `ListBox` when it makes its only call to the database.

Comment: Actually, it's stated specifically in the question that I'm trying to find "load times *of a listbox* that I'm binding my virtualized collections to."

Comment: The point here is to capture how long it takes to populate my ListBox given different loading scenarios...I have a lot of data to display (/page through) so this very much slows down ListBox performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for this. Make sure that you start it *before* you set the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property and stop it as you said, in the `ListBox.Loaded` event:

In XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" />
```

In code constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListBox.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ListBox_Loaded);
    Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000));
    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    ListBox.ItemsSource = Items;
}
```

Add the handler with a break point *after* the call to stop the `Stopwatch`:

```
private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

However, unless you have millions of rows of data, or extremely complicated `DataTemplates`, you *may* not see much differences. In this simple example, these 100,000,000 numbers are processed in well under one second. Even when I added a larger `DataTemplate` for the integers, it still rendered them all in just over one second. Furthermore, repeatedly running this scenario will return differing results, so this is somewhat unreliable as well.

Comment: Hmm, well thanks for this post. This got me what I needed to know for now. I am using DataTemplates and have millions of rows of data. I can see that Entity Framework 5 is very quick to "cache" my queries, but the `ListBox` takes a very long time (several seconds for around 5,000) to "reload" the collections bound to my queries.

Comment: @Rach, as an experiment, temporarily remove the `DataTemplate` so that your items are rendered simply as strings and take another time measurement... maybe your `DataTemplate` can be taking too much time to render. You could consider simplifying it a bit to save time maybe?

Comment: I actually did try this, with some noticeable improvement. Unfortunately, the `DataTemplate` is pretty simple to begin with and I do need it. I think with the DataVirtualization article I found [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.Uio8ODZQHAQ) and some EntityFramework improvements (reducing the number of items attached to the object graph) I should be able to improve virtualized "paging" of my data.